# org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'brightspotService'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Spring boot application works fine on my local but when I deploy it to K8s it shows error. Some context below:

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/v1/brightspot")
@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor_ = {@Autowired})
@CrossOrigin
public class BrightspotController {

  @Autowired
  protected BrightspotService brightspotService;

  /**
   * Hello world.
   *
   * @return the hello world
   */
  @GetMapping(value = "/helloWorld", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
  public String getHelloWorld() {
    return "Hello, World!!";
  }
  .
  .
  <more_methods>
  }
```

Service:

```
@Service
@NoArgsConstructor
public class BrightspotService {

  public static final String DISPLAY_IMAGE_URL = "displayImageUrl";
  public static final String AUTHOR_IMAGE_URL = "authorImageUrl";
  public static final String URL = "url";

  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BrightspotService.class);

  @Autowired
  protected BrightspotHelper brightspotHelper;

  /**
   * Get all articles via site search.
   *
   * @return response
   */
    public SearchResultModel getAllArticles() throws Exception {
    log.info("Received getAllArticles request");
    try {
      // TODO: Store searchResults in cache with expiry time of max 5 minutes
      String searchResults = brightspotHelper.makeBrightspotRequest(
          BrightspotHelper.SITE_SEARCH_URI, BrightspotHelper.SITE_SEARCH_QUERY);
      JSONObject searchResultsObj =
          brightspotHelper.appendImageUrl(new JSONObject(searchResults));
      SearchResultModel searchResultModel =
          ObjectMapperUtils.mapJson(searchResultsObj.toString(), SearchResultModel.class);

      log.info("Response {}", searchResultsObj.toString());
      return searchResultModel;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      log.warn(e.getMessage(), e);
      throw new Exception(e);
    }
  }
  .
  .
  <more-methods>
```

Helper:

```
@Component("BrightspotHelper")
@NoArgsConstructor
public class BrightspotHelper {

  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BrightspotHelper.class);
   
  .
  .
  <more-methods>
}
```

Error:

> 2021-03-23 23:14:19.493  WARN 1 --- [           main]
> ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered
> during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'brightspotService': Unsatisfied
> dependency expressed through field 'brightspotHelper'; nested
> exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
> Error creating bean with name 'BrightspotHelper': Lookup method
> resolution failed; nested exception is
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class
> [com.wayfair.projectphoenix.utils.BrightspotHelper] from ClassLoader
> [org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@529c2a9a]
> 2021-03-23 23:14:19.694  INFO 1 --- [           main]
> o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
> 2021-03-23 23:14:20.193  INFO 1 --- [           main]
> ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :
>
> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report
> re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. 2021-03-23 23:14:20.595
> ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication
> : Application run failed
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'brightspotService': Unsatisfied
> dependency expressed through field 'brightspotHelper'; nested
> exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
> Error creating bean with name 'BrightspotHelper': Lookup method
> resolution failed; nested exception is
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class
> [com.wayfair.projectphoenix.utils.BrightspotHelper] from ClassLoader
> [org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@529c2a9a]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1415)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:608)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944)
> at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:923)
> at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:588)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:767)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1311)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1300)
> at
> com.wayfair.projectphoenix.ExampleApplication.main(ExampleApplication.java:12)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
> Source)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
> Source)   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
> at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:107)
> at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
> Error creating bean with name 'BrightspotHelper': Lookup method
> resolution failed; nested exception is
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class
> [com.wayfair.projectphoenix.utils.BrightspotHelper] from ClassLoader
> [org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@529c2a9a]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1286)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1203)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:571)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640)
> ... 28 common frames omitted Caused by:
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class
> [com.wayfair.projectphoenix.utils.BrightspotHelper] from ClassLoader
> [org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@529c2a9a]     at
> org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:481)
> at
> org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:321)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:267)
> ... 40 common frames omitted Caused by:
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> org/springframework/boot/configurationprocessor/json/JSONObject   at
> java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)  at
> java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
> at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)     at
> org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:463)
> ... 42 common frames omitted Caused by:
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> org.springframework.boot.configurationprocessor.json.JSONObject   at
> java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)   at
> java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)     at
> org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:151)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)    ... 46
> common frames omitted

I also added qualifiers for service and helper class but was still having the same error.

Comment: This `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/configurationprocessor/json/JSONObject ` tells you exactly what is missing, a dependency.

Comment: @M.Deinum You're right. Can you post this as answer so I can accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a that contains `org.springframework.boot.configurationprocessor.json.JSONObject`.

That is what the exception `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/configurationprocessor/json/JSONObject` is telling you.

You either are missing a dependency or included to wrong version.

Answer (score 1):

Tried adding many versions of JSON dependency but it did not work, the dependency which worked for me to resolve the issue is spring-boot-configuration-processor

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: That's right. For some reason, only this one works! Cheers.